# Defining cluster in GridDB, test.gsh cannot be saved

Tags: variables, griddb

To define a cluster in GridDB, I first defined the variables for the nodes and then for the cluster itself. Afterward, I defined the SQL connection destination of a cluster using the command
`setclustersql firstclusterdemo democlustersql 239.0.0.1 41999`

Furthermore, I created a user and assigned some arbitrary variables. When I used the

> "show"

command to display all the defined variables, I successfully retrieved all the variables I had assigned.

However, the problem arose when I attempted to save the variables using the command

> save test.gsh

I encountered an error stating:

> test.gsh cannot be saved. :msg=[test.gsh (Permission denied)]

Throughout this process, I followed the instructions provided in this [document](https://www.toshiba-sol.co.jp/en/pro/griddb/docs-en/v4_5/GridDB_OperationToolsReference.html#displaying-recent-event-logs)

A screenshot with the error message and the commands I ran is available for reference.
[image: error screenshot]
I would appreciate any help or guidance to resolve this issue and successfully save the variables in the "test.gsh" script file. Thank you.

I have specified the script file as "test.gsh" and started the batch mode using the query

> "gs_sh test.gsh"

Then, I tried to execute the save query to save the variables, but encountered an error. I have checked the write permissions, and I do have the necessary permissions. I am working on Windows, so I attempted to use

> Run as Administrator

to have superuser privileges. Additionally, I tried using different directories, but unfortunately, it didn't resolve the issue. My goal is to successfully save the variables and their contents in the `.gsshrc` script file, which should be automatically imported during gs_sh start-up. Any help and assistance provided will be highly appreciated.